# Удаление расширения имени файла через Python

Tags: python, строки, файлы, расширения

Писал скрипт частью функционала которого является добавление к файлу второго расширения.
Было например `file.txt` и стало `file.txt.lol`.

Второй скрипт должен стереть второе расширение чтобы обратно стало `file.txt`.
Как это можно реализовать?

```py
os.rename(file.txt, file.txt + ".lol")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Средствами [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html):

```
from os import path

name = 'file.txt.lol'

no_lol, lol = path.splitext(name)  # В первую переменную попадет 'file.txt', во вторую - '.lol'
```

Средствами [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('file.txt.lol')
print(path.stem)  # Выведет file.txt (имя файла без расширения)
print(path.suffix)  # Выведет .lol
```

Еще вариант, когда есть путь (а не просто имя файла), нужно убрать расширение:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('somedir/file.txt.lol')
print(str(path.with_suffix(''))  # Выведет somedir/file.txt

# Стандартные функции Python умеют работать с объектами Path
# Переименовать файл из somedir/file.txt.lol в somedir/file.txt
os.rename(path, path.with_suffix(''))
```

---

Дальше варианты через методы строки, но тут нужно быть аккуратным, т.к. строка не понимает, что внутри нее путь, и с точки зрения строки `'some.path/file'` часть `'path/file'` внезапно может оказаться расширением, в то время как функции из `os.path` и `pathlib` поймут, где часть пути, а где расширение.

Средствами [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) (разбить по самому правому разделителю):

```
name = 'file.txt.lol'
name, dot, lol = name.rpartition('.')  # name='file.txt', dot='.', lol='lol'
```

Это примерно аналогично [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) с `maxsplit=1`:

```
name = 'file.txt.lol'
name, lol = name.rsplit('.', maxplit=1)
```

Единственно, `rsplit` вернет список из 1 элемента, если точки нет (из-за этого присваивание в две переменные упадет с ошибкой), а `rpartition` всегда возвращает кортеж из 3 элементов (если разделитель не будет найден, то первые два элемента будут пустыми строками).

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы изначальное знаете название файла и оно статично, тогда ссылка Вам подойдёт.
В другом случае, когда "file.txt" будет постоянно отличаться, советую Вам написать код, который будет забирать все файлы в указанной папке (директории) и парсить название, например.

```
import os
aa = 'test.txt.lol'
spl = aa.split('.')

for i in spl:
    if i == 'lol':
        spl.remove(i)
aa = '.'.join(spl)
```

где аа - это ваше название файла, которое вы уже можете применять в коде по ссылке в комментарии.